# ili9341 Not Working on STM32f4 discovery

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, lcd, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I am testing IlI9341 3.2 TFT LCD on stm32F4-discovery. I wired based on Discovery datasheet. I also read ILI9341 datasheet and went through all registers.
However I get nothing. Also, the LD7, LD5 and LD6 keep on indicating overflow of current. Compiled using Coocox IDE.
The functions SETCURSORPOSITION and FILL are further down.
Here is my code if someone can help me. Thank you.

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_fsmc.h"
#include "LCD.h"

#define LCD_REG     (*((volatile unsigned short *) 0x60000000))//address
#define LCD_RAM     (*((volatile unsigned short *) 0x60020000))//data

#define MAX_X       320//landscape mode
#define MAX_Y       240//landscape mode
#define ILI9341_PIXEL 76800

#define Green    0x07E0

void LCD_PinsConfiguration(void)
{
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD,ENABLE);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_7;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
GPIO_Init(GPIOD,&GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_7);

RCC_AHB3PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB3Periph_FSMC,ENABLE);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD,GPIO_PinSource0,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD,GPIO_PinSource1,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD,GPIO_PinSource4,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD,GPIO_PinSource5,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD,GPIO_PinSource8,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD,GPIO_PinSource9,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD,GPIO_PinSource10,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD,GPIO_PinSource11,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD,GPIO_PinSource14,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD,GPIO_PinSource15,GPIO_AF_FSMC);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0|GPIO_Pin_1|GPIO_Pin_4|GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_8|GPIO_Pin_9|GPIO_Pin_10|GPIO_Pin_11|GPIO_Pin_14|GPIO_Pin_15;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
GPIO_Init(GPIOD,&GPIO_InitStructure);

RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOE,ENABLE);

GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource2,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource7,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource8,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource9,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource10,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource11,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource12,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource13,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource14,GPIO_AF_FSMC);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource15,GPIO_AF_FSMC);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2|GPIO_Pin_7|GPIO_Pin_8|GPIO_Pin_9|GPIO_Pin_10|GPIO_Pin_11|GPIO_Pin_12|GPIO_Pin_13|GPIO_Pin_14|GPIO_Pin_15;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
GPIO_Init(GPIOD,&GPIO_InitStructure);

Delay(5000);

RCC_AHB3PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB3Periph_FSMC,ENABLE);
FSMC_NORSRAMInitTypeDef FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure;
FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitTypeDef FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure;

FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_AddressSetupTime = 0x0F;
FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_AddressHoldTime = 0;
FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_AddressSetupTime = 5;
FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_BusTurnAroundDuration =0;
FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_CLKDivision = 0;
FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_DataLatency =0;
FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_AccessMode = FSMC_AccessMode_A;

FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_Bank = FSMC_Bank1_NORSRAM1;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_DataAddressMux = FSMC_DataAddressMux_Disable;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_MemoryType = FSMC_MemoryType_SRAM;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_MemoryDataWidth = FSMC_MemoryDataWidth_16b;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_BurstAccessMode = FSMC_BurstAccessMode_Disable;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WaitSignalPolarity = FSMC_WaitSignalPolarity_Low;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WrapMode = FSMC_WrapMode_Disable;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WaitSignalActive = FSMC_WaitSignalActive_BeforeWaitState;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WriteOperation = FSMC_WriteOperation_Enable;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_AsynchronousWait = FSMC_AsynchronousWait_Disable;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_ExtendedMode = FSMC_ExtendedMode_Disable;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WriteBurst = FSMC_WriteBurst_Disable;
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_ReadWriteTimingStruct = &FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure;

FSMC_NORSRAMInit(&FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure);
FSMC_NORSRAMCmd(FSMC_Bank1_NORSRAM1,ENABLE);

}

void LCD_Initialization(void)
{
LCD_PinsConfiguration();

LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x01);
Delay(50000);

LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xcb);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x39);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x2C);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x34);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x02);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xcf);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0xC1);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x30);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xe8);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x85);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x78);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xea);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xed);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x64);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x03);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x12);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x81);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xf7);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x20);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xc0);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x23);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xc1);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x10);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xc5);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x3E);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x28);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xc7);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x86);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x36);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x48);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x3a);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x55);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xb1);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x18);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xb6);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x08);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x82);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x27);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xf2);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x2a);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0xEF);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x2b);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x01);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x3F);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x26);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x01);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xe0);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x0F);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x31);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x2B);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x0C);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x0E);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x08);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x4E);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0xF1);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x37);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x07);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x10);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x03);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x0E);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x09);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0xe1);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x00);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x0E);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x14);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x03);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x11);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x07);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x31);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0xC1);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x48);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x08);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x0F);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x0C);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x31);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x36);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(0x0F);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x11);

Delay(50000);

LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x29);
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x22);

}

void LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(uint16_t index)
{
    LCD_REG = index;
}

void LCD_ILI9341_SendData(uint16_t data)
{
    LCD_RAM = data;
}


void LCD_ILI9341_SetCursorPosition(uint16_t x1, uint16_t y1, uint16_t x2, uint16_t y2) {
LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x2A);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(x1 >> 8);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(x1 & 0xFF);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(x2 >> 8);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(x2 & 0xFF);

LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x2B);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(y1 >> 8);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(y1 & 0xFF);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(y2 >> 8);
LCD_ILI9341_SendData(y2 & 0xFF);
}

void LCD_ILI9341_Fill(uint16_t color) {
unsigned int n, i, j;
i = color >> 8;
j = color & 0xFF;
LCD_ILI9341_SetCursorPosition(0, 0, MAX_Y - 1, MAX_X - 1);

LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x0022);

for (n = 0; n < ILI9341_PIXEL; n++) {
    LCD_ILI9341_SendData(i);
    LCD_ILI9341_SendData(j);
}
}


void Delay(__IO uint32_t nCount)
{
while(nCount--)
{

}
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add the main code which is "int main{LCD_Initialization();  while(1){LCD_ILI9341_Fill(Green);}}."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question to make it clear things got solved. But I want to thank the community.
Actually I did few things: I removed GPIOE 2 from configuration block, because it was not being used. I replaced GPIOD to GPIOE in the same block. Inside "LCD_ILI9341_Fill" I changed "LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x0022)" to "LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x002C)". 0x002C is the actual Memory Write address to where you write the data on ili9341. I also connected the LCD RESET pin to the stm32f4 NRST pin. 3V power was connected to LCD LED_A.
Now everything works, I still get wrong colors but I need to make few changes on registers, such as register 36h.

Comment: LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x22); should also be changed to LCD_ILI9341_SendCommand(0x2C);.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a typo there, you're not configuring `GPIOE` at all.**

change the last `GPIO_Init()` call to

```
GPIO_Init(GPIOE,&GPIO_InitStructure);
```

instead of configuring the wrong pins of `GPIOD` again.

> I wired based on Discovery datasheet.

Do you mean the extension board datasheet? Because the Discovery datasheet says nothing about LCD controllers.

> LD7, LD5 and LD6 keep on indicating overflow of current

Are you sure? The overcurrent indicator is LD8 (red). You should expect some random lighting up or flickering of LD5, LD6, and LD8, because they are connected to the LCD data lines, but not on LD7.

Comment: I wired based on FSMC pin data. Yes, it is LD8 not 7. I changed to GPIOE, but no changes.

Comment: I also changed the second FSMC_AddressSetupTime  to FSMC_DataSetupTime.

Comment: Try connecting the display reset pin, and outputting a pulse